# Expose REST controller only during testing by using "test profile"

Tags: wildfly, cdi, resteasy, java-ee-7

For better testability of our application I'm adding a REST controller which allows setting certain states, e.g. `http://localhost:8090/test-api/customer` would allow creating a new customer in the application's database for further tests.

The class would basically look like this:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/test-api/customer")
public class TestController {

  @POST
  public void createCustomer() {}
}
```

Now I'd like this controller to be available only for testing, i.e. the production system should not expose this endpoint. Is there something like a "testing profile" or "testing annotation" like a Spring Boot profile I can add to this class to hide it from the production system?

Comment: I think it depends on how are you testing. If your tests are Arquillian, then adding a test-only resource is trivial. If by "testing" you mean a special build of your application that gets deployed only in test environments, then a solution is to (a) place the test controller in a Maven module dedicated to tests (b) create a profile in your war Maven module that includes the test module only if activated. If you deploy the same artifact (war or ear) to both test & prod environments, you might need something more sophisticated. So, can you provide more info?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos My first idea was that the same artifact (a war in this case) would be used for test and prod environment. But I'll think about your approach putting the code into a dedicated deployment. That might turn out to be a more realisitc solution.

Comment: I would consider that too. Having test artifacts in production scares me, even if I believe they are well hidden/deactivated. On the other hand with 2 different deployables you have to enforce procedures to ensure that the right one gets deployed in production, or there is trouble.